# What the Wakeby distribution is named after?

Tags: references

Quoting from paper Int. J. Climatol. 21: 1371–1384 (2001)

> The Wakeby distribution (WAD), defined by Thomas and introduced by Houghton (1978), is defined by the quantile function: $$ x(F) = \xi + \alpha \frac{1 - \left(1-F\right)^\beta}{\beta} - \gamma \frac{1 - \left(1-F\right)^{-\delta}}{\delta} $$

The [article](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/31278/mit-el-77-033wp-04146753.pdf?sequence=1) by Houghton, "Birth of a Parent: The Wakeby distribution for modeling flood flows" only says the following about the name:

> This paper introduces a new five-parameter distribution,
>   which we have named the Wakeby, ...

Harold A. Thomas, Jr. was Houghton's Ph.D. advisor.

**Q**: Who or what is the Wakeby distribution named after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a partly conflicting story. My source is James R. Wallis' privately published biography.

Harold A. Thomas Jr (1913-2002) suggested this 5-parameter distribution. John Greenwood and James R. Wallis named it:

> We called the distribution the Wakeby because Thomas's letter had come
>   from Cape Cod, where he summered on Wakeby Pond.

Wallis, J. 2010. *The Education of Jim Wallis.* Brunswick, ME: Camden Writers. p.183.

On Thomas, see [here](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/2005/03.03/26-mm.html).

For a map of Wakeby Pond, see [here](http://www.mass.gov/eea/docs/dfg/dfw/habitat/maps-ponds/dfwmashp.pdf).